# Change of select option does not trigger content load

Tags: javascript

In the firefox console, for a discogs artist page (e.g. https://www.discogs.com/artist/290587-JJ-Cale), I'm changing the select option and trigger the change event this way :

`document.getElementById("show").selectedIndex=4;`
`document.getElementById("show").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

However, it does not trigger the content load.

That must be because the page does not listen to the "change" event, as can be seen in the firefox console inspector (event button shows only the "invalid" event).

This is when the user is not logged in. When a user is logged in, the code is much different : "id" is not "show", but "limit_top", and the page listens to the "change" event.

`document.getElementById("limit_top").selectedIndex=4;` `document.getElementById("limit_top").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

This time, it triggers the content load.

When NOT logged in, manually changing the select option makes the content load. So there must be some kind of "event" that makes the content load. What "event" could that be ?

Comment: I tried `getEventListeners(document.getElementById("show"))` and there are none. That could mean it is delegated - this did not work either: `document.getElementById('show').selectedIndex=1; document.getElementById("app").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`